# Best way to autoplay video with Youtube iFrame API?... autoplay parameter vs onReady event.target.playVideo

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

From the Youtube iFrame API documentation there seems to be two different ways to autoplay a video. Does one way function or affect the Youtube player differently than the other?

**Method 1:** Set the `autoplay` parameter to '1' within the player options when you define a new Youtube player.

**Method 2:** Wait until the 'onReady' event fires, and then do event.target.playVideo(). Specifically:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: imho. autoplay should be disabled and video should play only if user click on play button.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric So assume the user clicked a play button. I now need to load the player and start playing it.